# CentOS server bash encoding issue

Tags: bash, encoding

I think I'm having issues with bash character encoding. The machine is CentOS 6.2 on a rackspace cloud.

For anyone not familiar with npm those characters should be vertical and horizontal pipes/bars that display the plugin hierarchy as a tree.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What's the SSH/console client? (The issue is more likely with that.)

Comment: Also, which encoding are you supposed to be using?

Comment: I'm using console2 on windows, which in turn is using msysgit as its shell (http://msysgit.github.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your remote server is using UTF-8 as its character set, as nearly all modern systems *except* Windows do, but neither Console2 nor msysgit support UTF-8 fully (or at all).

The solution, unfortunately, is going to be to replace one or both of these tools. In the case of msysgit, there is a [UTF-8 capable fork](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit-utf8/) available.